# Is it possible to check whether a static binary is compatible with a kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel

Basically, we want to run static programs compiled on one platform on another.

If it's not possible, what are the most significant changes in the kernel API between version 2.6.9 and 2.6.18?

Answer (score 2):

Linux binaries usually don't depend on specific kernel versions, unless you explicitly use a feature provided by a certain kernel.

Comment: What about the C library that is statically linked into the binary? I thought glibc depends on the kernel.

Comment: It does, but the kernel-userspace interface should remain constant between kernel releases. glibc uses that interface.

Comment: glibc certainly has a minimum kernel version that it will support but it's upwardly compatible from that point. The kernel ABI is very stable and developers care a lot about keeping backward compatible.

Answer (score 2):

Zero length mmap started to fail. :-)

Comment: I'll add a reference: See mmap(2) on Linux, BUGS section. This is required by SUSv3, and Linux behaves this way since 2.6.12